# How to set application icon using command line?

Tags: macos, icon

I created an application using "Script Editor".

I would like to override the default icon using command line vs the usual drag and drop approach.

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following approach worked to replace default icon (located at `/Applications/Hello World.app/Contents/Resources/applet.icns` for example) of "Hello World" application created using "Script Editor" with another `icns` icon file (Firefox icon for example).

```sh
cp "/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/firefox.icns" "/Applications/Hello World.app/Contents/Resources/applet.icns"
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -f "/Applications/Hello World.app"
```